# Cleanest way to dynamically call a non static method from a non static class?

Tags: c#

I am looking for the cleanest way. I am tempted to use delegates not sure though.

Comment: We need more information about what you're trying to do. Please give an example.

Comment: I didn't want to be too specific since I am willing to accodomate my code to fit into any clean solution. I just want a clean solution before I started coding anything.

Comment: Yes, but we've very little idea what you're really trying to do. What information do you have? Do you have an instance and the method name? What about parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like this?

```
class A
{
    public int Value;
    public int Add(int a) { return a + Value; }
    public int Mul(int a) { return a * Value; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Value = 10;
        Func<int, int> f;
        f = a.Add;
        Console.WriteLine("Add: {0}", f(5));
        f = a.Mul;
        Console.WriteLine("Mul: {0}", f(5));
    }
}
```

If you need the object it's called on to be unbound, like C++ member function pointers, I'm not sure that C# supports that. You can always use a lambda or delegate, though:

```
Func<A,int,int> f = delegate( A o, int i ) { return o.Add( i ); };
Console.WriteLine( "Add: {0}", f( a, 5 ) );
f = ( A o, int i ) => o.Mul( i );
Console.WriteLine( "Mul: {0}", f( a, 5 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add more details. Delegates are a good option option, as is reflection if you only have the method name, not an actual pointer to it.

Comment: I didn't want to be too specific since I am willing to accodomate my code to fit into any clean solution.